# how to access json data contained in a GET response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Continuing yesterday's saga, now I can retrieve json objects in a response but I can't extract the data from them.

The following node.js snippet is from the file "accounts.js" which is in an ETrade api library that exists in the path /lib.  It returns json containing data about the accounts of the authenticated user. The authentication part is working great.

```js
exports.listAccounts = function(successCallback,errorCallback)
{
    var actionDescriptor = {
            method : "GET",
            module : "accounts",
            action : "accountlist",
            useJSON: true,
    };
    
    this._run(actionDescriptor,{},successCallback,errorCallback);
};
```

The ETrade website says this call will produce the following sample response:

```js
{
   "AccountListResponse": {
     "Account": [
       {
         "accountDesc": "MyAccount-1",
         "accountId": "83405188",
         "marginLevel": "MARGIN",
         "netAccountValue": "9999871.82",
         "registrationType": "INDIVIDUAL"
       },
       {
         "accountDesc": "MyAccount-3",
         "accountId": "83405553",
         "marginLevel": "CASH",
         "netAccountValue": "100105468.99",
         "registrationType": "INDIVIDUAL"
       },
       {
         "accountDesc": "SIMPLE IRA",
         "accountId": "83405188",
         "marginLevel": "CASH",
         "netAccountValue": "99794.13",
         "registrationType": "IRA"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

In my app.js file, I have the following:

```js
var etrade = require('./lib/etrade');
var et = new etrade(configuration);


        et.listAccounts( 
            function(res){
                var listAccountsRes = res;            
                console.log('account list success!');
                console.log(listAccountsRes)
        },
            function(error) {
                console.log("Error encountered while attempting " +
                            "to retrieve account list: " +
                             error);
        });
```

When I run this code, the console log shows the following message:

```js
{ 'json.accountListResponse':
  { response:
     [ [Object],
     [ [Object],
     [ [Object],
     [ [Object],
     [ [Object],
     [ [Object],
     [ [Object],
     [ [Object] ] } }
```

Suppose in app.js I want to put the accounts data in a variable called myAccounts.

One of our members, Jack, solved yesterday's problem and when I commented that I still couldn't access the data in the response, he suggested this: "That property has a dot in it so you'll have to use [ ... ] rather than dot notation to access it. See what's inside the objects with a['json.accountListResponse'].response."  So far I have not been able to get that to work, even when I use `['json.accountListResponse'].res` like this:

```
var listAccountsRes = [json.accountListResponse].res;
```

This returns undefined when printed to the console.

Thanks to Adam for his suggestion which led to this which works:

```js
var listAccountsRes = res['json.accountListResponse'];
                var listAccounts = listAccountsRes['response'];
                console.log('account list success!');
                console.log(listAccounts)
```

Now the console log reports almost exactly what ETrade says I should get. (They appear to have changed the name "Account" to "response").  I presume my variable listAccounts now contains the json with eight sample accounts in it that I can see in my console log.  But I still don't know how to access individual elements.  There should be some simple code that will iterate over the json file and produce an array of arrays that I could actually use for something.  I tried accessing it like an array: console.log(listAccounts[0]) but that returns undefined.  Do I need to stringify it or something?

Comment: I think you want to do `var listAccountsRes = res['json.accountListResponse'];` instead.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  This works.

Comment: To iterate the array use array.map() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map